base64image econded string 500 internal error in asp.net core web api inhostinger server
base64image econded string 500 internal error in asp.net core web api in hostinger server
We have deployed the Asp.net core Web API in hostinger VPS linux with ASP.NET Template and Nginx proxy server.
POST Api working fine in local development but not hostinger vps server when api categoryImage property contents base64image string in it and other api post works which don't have base64 image ecoded.
{
"categoryName": "string",
"categoryImage": "string", //Base64 image string
"categoryBanner": "string"  //Base64 image string
}
when we send the any string other base64 image string then it post action works fine.
Any suggestions will very helpful
We tried to put any other string than base64, try the see the logging. didn't find any any specific issue on it.

Since you are using linux machine, we can set MaxRequestBodySize like below.
builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel(options =>
{
    options.Limits.MaxRequestBodySize = 100 * 1024 * 1024; // Set the Max Size 100MB
});

